# .htaccess: redirect to sub directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've written a Wordpress plugin which creates `.html` files. I'm trying to get it so that when a visitor hits `sitename.com/newsletters` it shows the `index.php` file in `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/files`

Of course, the index.php file is a list of all the other files in the directory, so when someone hits `sitename.com/newsletters/january.html` the browser loads `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/files/january.html`, but the URL remains `http://sitename.com/newsletters/january.html`

I thought this should take care of it, but it's not working. Just gives me a "Post not found" error.

`RewriteRule ^newsletters/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/files/$1 [L]`

Here's my `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^newsletters/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/files/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule looks good and does what it is supposed to do.

But in an .htaccess file, when a URL is rewritten, the resulting URL is fed back into the rules once more.

There it skips `RewriteRule ^newsletters/...`, and comes to `RewriteRule . /index.php`. But index.php, the main entry point for Wordpress doesn't know about your files in `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/files/`.

To fix this, you must prevent index.php swallowing your rewrite. You can do this by prefixing your `RewriteRule` with

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/files/ - [L]
```

which exits the rule chain without rewriting further.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the great explanation :)